# Looking to snap object, only when object is close enough

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, drag, snapping

SO this may be an easy solution, but I can't seem to figure it out myself. 
What I am doing, is creating a drag n drop game, and it's all well and beautiful, but if you let go of the piece too early, it automatically snaps to the nearest available location (based on positions I have in an array to choose from). I'm really looking for it only to snap if it's say within the confines of the movieclip it's over, or if it's within a 20px radius of a movieclip. 
Hope you guys can help me! It is inititated on a mouseUp event.

Code:

```
var dragArray:Array = [it_1, it_2, it_3, it_4, it_5, it_6, it_7, it_8, it_9];
var matchArray:Array = [mat_1, mat_2, mat_3, mat_4, mat_5, mat_6, mat_7, mat_8, mat_9]
var placeArray:Array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
// points to snap to
var pointList:Array = new Array();
pointList.push(new Point(mat_1.x, mat_1.y));
pointList.push(new Point(mat_2.x, mat_2.y));
pointList.push(new Point(mat_3.x, mat_3.y));
pointList.push(new Point(mat_4.x, mat_4.y));
pointList.push(new Point(mat_5.x, mat_5.y));
pointList.push(new Point(mat_6.x, mat_6.y));
pointList.push(new Point(mat_7.x, mat_7.y));
pointList.push(new Point(mat_8.x, mat_8.y));
pointList.push(new Point(mat_9.x, mat_9.y));
////where points are placed after being snapped to
var spliced:Array= new Array();

function SnapEvent(event:MouseEvent) {

 //// the clip we're dragging////
var referencePoint:Point = new Point(currentClip.x, currentClip.y);
var resultPoints:Array = PointTester.findClosest(referencePoint, pointList, 1);

////returns nearest "mat" and snaps current clip to it////
for each(var result:Object in resultPoints) {
//trace("Point is at:", result.point.x, ", ", result.point.y, " that's ", result.distance, " units away");
        currentClip.x=result.point.x;
        currentClip.y=result.point.y;
        var posOfMat:int = pointList.indexOf(result.point);
        trace("index: "+pointList[posOfMat]);
        spliced.push(pointList[posOfMat]);
        pointList.splice(posOfMat,1);
        //trace("spliced: "+spliced);
        trace("length: "+pointList.length); 
        }
        //trace("result: "+result.point);
        trace("full spliced: "+spliced.length);
}
```

Comment: What is your specific issue ? You don't know how to calculate distance ? You don't know how to compare distance results to get the closest ?

Comment: It currently is comparing through the pointList array to find the closest one. The problem here, is I only want it to start comparing when I'm say 10 pixels away from one.

Comment: So just have a conditional that doesn't evaluate points unless they are within that distance.

Comment: Currently I see nothing in your code that even calculates distance, so it currently isn't comparing distances. Or does PointTester.findCloset return that ?

Comment: Sorry I am using a class called PointTester that uses the function "findClosest" to do the comparison. as seen in the variable resultPoints

Comment: Your code is very confusing. What does findClosest return ? An array of closest points ? Why ? Shouldn't it only return the closest, meaning a single point ?

Comment: If I am reading your question correctly, you simply need to just exclude any points that are not within the max distance range. I am guessing that in your findClosest method you can just exclude anything where the distance is not in that range. However I can't really evaluate that method as it's not posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `for each` loop you can check to see whether or not the result point's distance is less than 20 pixels, and only snap the current clip to the result point if it is. Here's an example:

```
...

function SnapEvent(event:MouseEvent) {

    //// the clip we're dragging////
    var referencePoint:Point = new Point(currentClip.x, currentClip.y);
    var resultPoints:Array = PointTester.findClosest(referencePoint, pointList, 1);

    ////returns nearest "mat" and snaps current clip to it////
    for each(var result:Object in resultPoints) {
        if(result.distance < 20){ //if the result point's distance is less than 20 pixels away from the current clip
            currentClip.x=result.point.x; // snap the current clips position
            currentClip.y=result.point.y;
            var posOfMat:int = pointList.indexOf(result.point);
            trace("index: "+pointList[posOfMat]);
            spliced.push(pointList[posOfMat]);
            pointList.splice(posOfMat,1);
            //trace("spliced: "+spliced);
            trace("length: "+pointList.length);
        }
        //otherwise do nothing
    }
    //trace("result: "+result.point);
    trace("full spliced: "+spliced.length);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: That COMPLETELY helped, you knew exactly what I was going for. THANK YOU. Sometimes it's one of those things, someone else shows you and you just have an "ah doy!" moment.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of logic, here's what I would do :

Loop through locations (your `pointList`)

Push an object containing the location and the distance from your piece into an array

Sort resulting array in ascending order based on distance property of the objects

First element of the resulting sorted array is your closest location

Comment: I have 9 objects that snap to 9 other objects. Here, it picks up where the current object i'm grabbing is and from there,the closest point which is in array "resultPoints"- which is a combination of current location and an element of pointList.Resulting with closest to the current location. If you begin to pull an object then immediately let go before you are near a "mat"  (which each "mat" is where you can place a draggable object, and whose x and y values are listed in the pointList) it just grabs the nearest mat nearby, even though you've barely moved the draggable item.